# In Laravel I am trying to append one of my header sections from an include in the footer - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, append, sections

Simplified my main.blade.php template looks like this...

```
 <html>
      <head>
           @inlcude("header")
           @yield("addToHeader")
      </head>
      <body>
           @yield("content")
           @include("footer")
      </body>
 </html>
```

Let's say my controller points to login.blade.php and it provides *addToHeader* and *content* sections. When my footer is included, I'd like to append the *addToHeader* section but I just can't get it to work.

In my footer I have tried

```
 @section("addToHeader")
      @parent
      This is the added content
      @yield("addToHeader")
 @stop
```

And variations of this.

Now, for the sake of doing it right and in hopes that I might not spend my resources on doing this the incorrect or inefficient way, here is what I am trying to accomplish by doing this...

When a user logs in every time they try to load a new page, I want the website to throw a message to the user (in my case I am actually "locking" the page down with a modal) that lets the user know he/she must finish setting up her profile before anything else can be done. Is there a controller or route that doesn't care which page/action is being requested and allows me to send extra data to the template - even if it is just *$data["lockdown"]=true*?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it but i would go for something like this.

Using a session variable to know if the user has to set-up his profile or not:

```
Session::put('profile_uncompleted',true);
```

You can set this variable when the user log-in for exemple.

Then on your main.blade.php you can check if you have to display your modal:

```
@if(Session::has('profile_uncompleted')
  @include('modal')
@endif
```

Where modal contains your Html modal content.